# Best integer at root node Cplex with pyomo

Tags: cplex, pyomo

I am using pyomo with CPLEX as solver. Is there any function to get the Best integer solution and the variables solution at the root node (LP relaxation) like the `getValue` and `getBestObjValue`?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a [limit on the number of nodes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/NodeLim.html) to 1.  The solver would stop after processing the root node, and you can query the information that you're interested in.  Then, remove the limit and solve again. The solver should just continue where it was, without loosing the work that was already done.

Comment: I had mentioned that there is no function to do this, but that is incorrect, and one can use callbacks.